# How to draw a big binary tree with depth of at most 10 and leaves 120 in 1 page

Tags: forest, trees

Hi this is my first time asking question. Lately, I was instructed to draw an ultra big binary tree with depth at most 10 and 120 leaves. I have tried to reverse the tree counter clockwise for 90 degrees. However, it is still too big for latex to show it in one page. I would like to ask for a solution for drawing a big tree.

[image: A screenshot of the pain]

The following is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newgeometry{left=0cm,bottom=1in}
\section*{Problem 4}\label{sec:q4}
\subsection*{(a).}\label{sec:q4a}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,%tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=1mm,minimum height=1mm, % node shape
        l sep=1mm % level distance
    }
    [a1:a5
    [a2:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [12345,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [21345,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [13245,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [23145,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [32145,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [31245,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]
    [a1:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [12435,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [21435,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [13425,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [31425,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [14325,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [14235,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]
    [a2:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [23415,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [32415,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [24315,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [24135,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [34215,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [34125,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [42315,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [43215,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [42135,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [43125,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [a3:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [41325,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [41235,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]]]]
    [12354,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [12453,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [12543,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]
    ]]
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [13452,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [13542,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [14532,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [15342,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]]]]
    [a2:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [23451,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [23541,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [24531,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [25341,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]]
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [34521,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [35241,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [45231,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [52341,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! When I correct your code using `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\section*{Problem 4}\label{sec:q4}
\subsection*{(a).}\label{sec:q4a}

\begin{forest} ... \end{forest}
\end{document}` it does seem to fit on one page. Can you please make the code compilable (by adding `\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}`)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing my mistake! In fact, I added `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}`
$ in my code previously, may I also ask what's the difference between this and `\usepackage{forest}`?

Comment: I do not really know, but the manual says that you can locally switch on the library with `\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}`. So maybe the solution is to just use `\usepackage{forest}` and switch the linguistics library on wherever it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I find it does fit if you decrease the distance between siblings even if you load `forest` with the `linguistics` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\section*{Problem 4}\label{sec:q4}
\subsection*{(a).}\label{sec:q4a}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,%tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=1mm,minimum height=1mm, % node shape
        l sep=3mm, % level distance
        s sep=0.5mm
    }
    [a1:a5
    [a2:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a1:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [12345,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [21345,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [13245,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [23145,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [32145,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [31245,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]
    [a1:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [12435,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [21435,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [13425,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [31425,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a1:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [14325,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [14235,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]
    [a2:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [23415,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [32415,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [24315,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [24135,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]
    [a3:a4,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [34215,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [34125,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a2:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a2:a3,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [42315,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [43215,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [42135,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]
    [a3:a1,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [43125,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [a3:a2,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [41325,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [41235,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]]]]
    [12354,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [12453,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [12543,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]
    ]]
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [13452,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [13542,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [14532,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [15342,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$<$}}]]]]
    [a2:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [23451,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [23541,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [24531,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [25341,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]]
    [a3:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}
    [34521,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [35241,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]
    ]
    [a4:a5,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}
    [45231,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$\leq$}}]
    [52341,edge label={node[midway,fill=white]{$>$}}]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]